# Why is integral by parts not working in Gaussian expectation calculation?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, expected-value

My Procedure:

$$\begin{align*} 
E(x)=&\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \\
=  &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}xe^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx
\end{align*}$$
Using integral by parts: let

$$u=x$$ $$dv=e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$
we have $$du=dx$$ and $$v = \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}dv=\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$
Since we know the integral of a pdf is 1: $\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=1$, then we have $$v=\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma$$

Then, $$uv-\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}vdu = x\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma dx$$

It seems something's wrong. But where?

Comment: I was very confused at first, but I think I see your mistake. You don't obtain $v$ by integrating $dv$, you obtain $v(t)$ by integrating $dv$ from any $t_0$ to $t$, hence $v(t) = \int_{t_0}^t e^{-\frac{(x- \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx$.

Comment: @BrunoB is correct.  $v$ is a function, not a constant.

Comment: If you're evaluating $\int_1^2 5x^4\log x\,dx$ using integration by parts, choosing $dv=5x^4\,dx$: would you say that $v=\int_1^2 5x^4\,dx = 31$? No, you'd say that $v=\int 5x^4\,dx = x^5+C$ (rather, you'd choose your favourite antiderivative, say $v=x^5$). The same thing is true here: $v$ shouldn't be a constant, but rather a function that is an antiderivative of the $dv$ function.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you for your explanation. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral can be solved as follows.

$E(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}(x-\mu)e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx+\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$ .

By letting $t=(x-\mu)^2$, the first integral of the right-hand side (RHS) becomes

$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{+\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{t}{2\sigma^2}}dt=0$,

while the second integral of the RHS is obviously

$\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\mu$.

Thus, the final result is $E(x)=\mu$ as well known.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Actually, I know this method but when I tried to use integral by parts to solve it, I forgot some calculus knowledge. Anyways, thank you a lot for typing the nicely formulated solution. It will definitely help others.